# Зачем нужны события, если есть делегаты?

Tags: c#

Объясните, почему события это не повторяющийся за делегатами бред, в чем их смысл и как они работают. Потому что я не понимаю абсолютно, что за чем идет, откуда оно работает и зачем они нужны, если делегаты работают ТОЧНО ТАКЖЕ, только делегаты еще и более гибкие по сравнению с событиями. Ситуация похожа на лямбды и анонимные методы, когда вторые делают то же, что первые, но намного удобнее, но почему то некоторые люди - пережитки прошлого все еще упоминают лямбду. Психанул

Comment: Делегаты в интерфейсе не объявишь, а события можешь. И лямбды не трожь!

Comment: Анонимные методы появились до лямбд, и лямбды в умеют и компилироваться в деревья выражений